# ObjectNotExecutableError when executing any SQL query using AsyncEngine

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, asyncpg

I'm using async_engine. When I try to execute anything:

```
async with self.async_engine.connect() as con:
    query = "SELECT id, name FROM item LIMIT 50;"
    result = await con.execute(f"{query}")
```

I'm getting:

```
Exception has occurred: ObjectNotExecutableError
Not an executable object: 'SELECT id, name FROM item LIMIT 50;'
```

---

This question was asked before by user [@stilmaniac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8485707/stilmaniac) but it is now [deleted from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68544256/sqlalchemy-v1-4-objectnotexecutableerror-using-asyncengine).

I found it in Google Search cache, [here is copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADhVc.png).

I have the same issue so I'm reasking it, but the original version is below:

---

I'm trying to create tables from metadata as follows:

```
Base = declarative_base()

properties = Table(
    'properties', Base.metadata,
    # ...
    Column('geolocation', Geography(geometry_type='POINT', srid=4326)),
    # ... 
)

engine = create_async_engine("postgresql+asyncpg://user:password@postgres/")
async with engine.begin() as conn:
    await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
```

Gives me the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ObjectNotExecutableError: Not an executable object: 'CREATE INDEX "idx_properties_geolocation" ON "properties" USING GIST ("geolocation")'
```

Considering this [doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#synopsis-core)

Versions:

- OS: macOS 11.4 ARM
- SQLAlchemy: 1.4.22
- Python: 3.6

Comment: Have you tried using it without f strings?

Comment: @ReedJones `f"{}"` gives the same result as `str()`, it wasn't the cause.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

As the exception message suggests, the `str` `'SELECT id, name FROM item LIMIT 50;'` is not an executable object.  To make it executable, wrap it with [sqlalchemy.text](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text).

```py
from sqlalchemy import text

async with self.async_engine.connect() as con:
    query = "SELECT id, name FROM item LIMIT 50;"
    result = await con.execute(text(query))
```

[async.connection.execute](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.AsyncConnection.execute) requires that its statement argument

> [...] is always an object that is in both the ClauseElement and
> Executable hierarchies, including:
>
> - Select
> - Insert, Update, Delete
> - TextClause and TextualSelect
> - DDL and objects which inherit from DDLElement

The synchronous [connection.execute](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execute) method permits raw strings, but this is deprecated in v1.4 and has been removed in SQLAlchemy 2.0.

Answer (score 6):

It is due to sqlalchemy treats query as string,
below workaround is working

```
from sqlalchemy import text
query = 'insert into table_name values(1,2,3)'
 with pool.connect() as db_conn:
     db_conn.execute(text(query))
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to [this thread](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/51061)

Workaround: To avoid this bug, I just reverted the version of SQLAlchemy back to older than 2.0 :

1. Firstly, confirm if your SQLAlchmey version is 2.0 or beyond. To do so, run

```bash
pip show sqlalchemy
```

Which will show something like this:

```
Verify current version from output:
Name: SQLAlchemy
Version: 2.0.9

Summary: Database Abstraction Library
Home-page: https://www.sqlalchemy.org
Author: Mike Bayer
Author-email: mike_mp@zzzcomputing.com
License: MIT
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires: typing-extensions
Required-by: pandasql
```

2. Revert back to older version (install a specific version of SQLAlchemy using below command):

```bash
pip install SQLAlchemy==1.4.17
```

Confirm the version once:

```bash
pip show sqlalchemy
```

Rerun your script.

Comment: Downvoted because that’s a complicated solution (going back to 1.4 may require changing a lot of code) to a non-problem: the accepted answer already works with SQLAlchemy 2.0.

Comment: @bfontaine and yet it saved my day, thus +1 ;-] It's not a _non-problem_ if you accidentally install the latest version and wonder what's going on? Upgrading may require changing a lot of code.