# How to drop and create SQL table using SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have data in a SQL table. I have some processes where I append extra data, but there are extra columns present. In order to append successfully, I read in the entire SQL table, `pd.concat` the new data, drop the original table, and then write this back to SQL.

This works with this:

```
database_con = f'mssql://@{server}/{database}?driver={driver}'

engine = create_engine(database_con)
con = engine.connect()
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':['a','b','c']})
df.to_sql(
            name='#temp01',
            con=con,
            if_exists="append",
            index=False
        )

query = 'select * from #temp01'
data = pd.read_sql_query(query, con)
data

# new data
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':['test_20230925'], 'column2':[234],  'column3':[234.56]})
df_new = pd.concat([data,df])

drop_query = """ drop table #temp01"""
pd.read_sql_query(drop_query, con)

df_new.to_sql(
            name='#temp01',
            con=con,
            if_exists="append",
            index=False
        )

query = "select * from #temp01"
new_data = pd.read_sql_query(query, con)
new_data
```

the `pd.read_sql_query(drop_query, con)` works, but returns `qlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.`

I would like to drop the original table without this return, and have tried

```
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(drop_query)
```

with the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ObjectNotExecutableError: Not an executable object: ' drop table #temp01'

as well as

```
tbl = '#temp01'
con.execute(schema.DropTable(tbl, if_exists=True))
```

but I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'

and

```
schema.DropTable(tbl, if_exists=True)
con.commit()
```

returns

> <sqlalchemy.sql.ddl.DropTable object at 0x0000019CE1ABF990>

but when I check the status of the table, it has not been updated.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69491015/5320906) answer your question?

Comment: yes, thanks @snakecharmerb