# How can I automatically store procedures at the init of my db via SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy, mariadb, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a backend pod that I generate via a CI build and use it to also init my mariadb via SQLalchemy/Flask. I had some stored procedure on my common non-docker architecture before that I also need to implement in my new db automatically.

I have them stored in a bunch of .sql files and tried to itterate through them and executing each of those via the connection.execute() and it gave me :

Error occurred: Not an executable object

Even tho those procedures are fine to work with when it's manually stored in the maria-db.

Any advices are welcome

Comment: per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69490450/objectnotexecutableerror-when-executing-any-sql-query-using-asyncengine) `connection.execute` is deprecated. Use the newer method.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.